# Как отсортировать объект с вложенными объектами, по значению свойства вложенных?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Не могу отсортировать объекты по увеличению цены.

```
let obj = {
    246: {
        "price": 819
    },
    248: {
        "price": 819
    },
    249: {
        "price": 819
    },
    250: {
        "price": 819
    },
    316: {
        "price": 819
    },
    317: {
        "price": 479
    },
    649: {
        "price": 479
    }
};

const sorted = Object.keys(obj)
  .sort((a, b) =>
      obj[a].price - obj[b].price
  ).reduce(
      (_sortedObj, key) => ({
          ..._sortedObj,
          [key]: obj[key]
      }),
      {}
  );
  
document.write(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Обычные объекты (экземпляры `Object`) в JS не сохраняют порядок добавления их свойств с числовыми ключами (именами свойств).
Точнее, при *перечислении* свойств в таких объектах, они автоматически сортируются по возрастанию ключей. Поэтому, сортировка значений свойств в обычном объекте, практически бесполезна в данном случае. Можно сказать, что она "невозможна" - по крайней мере, без изменения имен свойств на возрастающие/убывающие в порядке возрастания/убывания их значений.

Но, такая сортировка возможна при использовании объекта [**`Map`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) в роли объекта-контейнера, т.к. `Map` и сохраняет порядок вставки элементов, и соблюдает данный порядок при их перечислении:

```js
let obj = {
  246: { price: 819 },
  248: { price: 819 },
  249: { price: 819 },
  250: { price: 819 },
  316: { price: 819 },
  317: { price: 479 },
  649: { price: 479 },
};

const sorted = Object.keys(obj)
  .sort((a, b) => obj[a].price - obj[b].price)
  .reduce((rslt, key) => rslt.set(key, obj[key]), new Map());

// вывод элементов в sorted (в порядке их следования в этом объекте):
for (const [key, obj] of sorted.entries())
  console.log(`${key}: ${JSON.stringify(obj)}`);
```

Изменить порядок следования элементов уже после их добавления в объект данного типа - весьма сложно. Для изменения порядка следования (если оно потребуется), будет проще создать новый экземпляр `Map` из старого... то есть, простота повторной сортировки достижима, но ценой производительности.

Обрати внимание, что для чтения элемента `Map` по ключу - вместо квадратноскобочной нотации

```
sorted[316]      //  undefined
```

используется метод `get`:

```
sorted.get(316)  //  { price: 819 }
```

,а  для присвоения - метод `set`, как показано в примере.

Информация об остальных методах содержится по ссылке в начале ответа.

---

**Другим вариантом решения** может быть использование массива объектов с дополнительным уровнем вложенности (схема вида `{ key: { price: number } }[]`):

```js
let obj = {
  246: { price: 819 },
  248: { price: 819 },
  249: { price: 819 },
  250: { price: 819 },
  316: { price: 819 },
  317: { price: 479 },
  649: { price: 479 },
};

const sorted = Object.keys(obj)
  .sort((a, b) => obj[a].price - obj[b].price)
  .map(key => ({ [key]: obj[key] }));

console.log(JSON.stringify(sorted));
```

Но так теряется возможность быстрого доступа по начальному ключу (как в исходном объекте), т.к. ключом элемента *массива* является целочисленный индекс (равный порядковому номеру элемента, отсчет с нуля), а начальные ключи исходного объекта здесь становятся свойствами вложенных объектов.
Для получения объекта с нужным ключом - в таком случае придется использовать перебирающий метод с получением ключей, а это выглядит громоздко и выполняется значительно медленнее:

```
sorted.find(itm => Object.keys(itm)[0] == 316)  //  { '316': { price: 819 }}
```

Поэтому, использование `Map` вместо такого массива "оберток", окажется более удобным в большинстве случаев.

Comment: Спасибо за ликбез. Все теперь понятно.

Answer (score 1):

Насколько я понимаю, так не получится, ведь в результате у вас не массив объектов, а объект объектов, а ключи объектов, состоящие из чисел, автоматически сортируются в числовом порядке. Так что или создавайте таки массив объектов, или добавляйте к ключам какой-то строковой префикс, чтобы они не сортировались автоматически, а сохраняли порядок создания (вроде `` [`_${key}`]: obj[key] `` вместо `[key]: obj[key]`).