# Как перебрать многомерный массив на JS с помощью foreach?

Tags: javascript, foreach

Извините за глупый вопрос, запутался в синтаксисе.

Хочу перебрать многомерный массив с кучей вложений, пример:

```
Array(50)
0: {ID: "46998", IBLOCK_ID: "36", NAME: "Toyota", IBLOCK_SECTION_ID: null, CREATED_BY: "12", PROPERTY_152: {213156: "9284"}}
1: {ID: "47000", IBLOCK_ID: "36", NAME: "Toyota", IBLOCK_SECTION_ID: null, CREATED_BY: "12", PROPERTY_152: {213162: "9284"}}
2: {ID: "47002", IBLOCK_ID: "36", NAME: "Toyota", IBLOCK_SECTION_ID: null, CREATED_BY: "12", PROPERTY_152: {213170: "9284"}}
3: {ID: "47004", IBLOCK_ID: "36", NAME: "Toyota", IBLOCK_SECTION_ID: null, CREATED_BY: "12", PROPERTY_152: {213180: "9284"}}
4: {ID: "47006", IBLOCK_ID: "36", NAME: "Toyota", IBLOCK_SECTION_ID: null, CREATED_BY: "12", PROPERTY_152: {213192: "9934"}}
```

Таким способом перебираю его в PHP и вывожу в таблицу (вывожу значение одной переменной, просто для примера):

```
  <?php
                                            
                                            $id_K = $_REQUEST['PLACEMENT_OPTIONS'];
                                            $id_K = preg_replace("/[^0-9]/", '', $id_K);
                                            $id_E = $v2['ID'];

                                            
                                            foreach ((array) $result as $k=>$v){
                                                foreach ((array) $v as $k2=>$v2){
                                                 foreach ((array) $v2 as $k3=>$v3){   
                                                  foreach ((array) $v3 as $k4=>$v4){  
                                          if ($v4==$id_K)            
                                            echo '<tr>
                                                <td><strong>'.'1'.'</strong></td>'
                                                .'<td>'.$v2['ID'].'</td>'
                                                .'<td>'.$v2['NAME'].'</td>'
                                                .'<td>'.$v2['NAME'].'</td>'
                                                .'<td>'.$v2['NAME'].'</td>'
                                                .'<td>'.$v2['NAME'].'</td>'
                                                .'<td>'.$v2['NAME'].'</td>
                                                                                            </tr>'; }}}} ?>
```

Как мне подобное повторить на JS? Пытаюсь сделать так:

Массив находится в переменной listTech

```
for(var i = 0; i < listTech.length; i++)
{
    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
    tr.innerHTML =
        '<td>' + listTech[i].ID + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + listTech[i].NAME + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + listTech[i].PROPERTY_152[0] + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + listTech[i] + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + listTech[i] + '</td>' +
        '<td>' + listTech[i] + '</td>';
    tbody.appendChild(tr);
}
```

В принципе, я его уже перебрал разными способами. Но интересует вопрос, как мне получить доступ к значению вложенного массива PROPERTY_152, если ключи в этом массиве не повторяются? Как написать, что я хочу получить значение по индексу 0 из массива PROPERTY_152? listTech[i].PROPERTY_152*значение 0 индекса*

Comment: В вопросе надо заменить php-дамп переменной на реальные данные (тот же массив, но уже в том виде как его получит JS), потому что данные тут являются условием задачи. Еще лучше будет оформить этот массив не просто куском текста, а в js-коде, вместе с собственной попыткой решения - то есть, как [repro].

Comment: @yar85, как-то так?

Comment: Так я же не знаю как твоя клиентская часть (на JS) будет получать данные. Если в таком виде, как указано в вопросе - значит так. Хотя я бы посоветовал генерировать серверный ответ в каком-то более "съедобном" формате, типа JSON или YAML... но это уже не относится к вопросу :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если без парсинга того формата данных который указан в вопросе (предполагая что скрипт уже распарсил данные в js-массив и поместил результат в переменную `listTech`), то код добавления ячеек таблицы с перебором через `forEach` будет примерно таким:

```
const tBody = document.querySelector('#your-table tbody');
listTech.forEach(item => {
  const tr = tBody.insertRow();
  tr.insertCell().textContent = item.ID;
  tr.insertCell().textContent = item.NAME;
  tr.insertCell().textContent = Object.values(item.PROPERTY_152)[0];  // получаем значение первого свойства вложенного объекта в свойстве `PROPERTY_152`
  for (let i = 0; i < 3; ++i)  // добавляем три пустых ячейки, как и код в вопросе
    tr.insertCell();
});
```

---

> Но интересует вопрос, как мне получить доступ к значению вложенного массива PROPERTY_152, если ключи в этом массиве не повторяются?

Значением свойства `PROPERTY_152` является **объект**, а не массив.
Обратиться к первому свойству объекта можно либо по имени этого свойства (когда оно известно), либо получив список всех значений свойств в виде массива и взяв значение его нулевого элемента:

```
Object.values(listTech[i].PROPERTY_152)[0]
```

Но когда в объекте может быть несколько свойств, полагаться на порядок их следования не стоит (сохранение этого порядка не гарантируется) - лучше считывать значение свойства по его имени.

Comment: Спасибо огромное за пример и разъяснение! Тяжело в учении , как говорится :)

Comment: @Виктор, пожалуйста. Еще о том почему не стоит полагаться на порядок следования имен свойств в объектах: тут недавно был задан [такой вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1303883/288409), где автор на практике столкнулся с проблемой из-за автосортировки "ключей" в js-объекте. Когда есть возможность бэкэндом обеспечить более однозначную структуру (например, возвращая массив объектов у которых их ключ перемещен в свойство), лучше так и поступать.

Comment: спасибо большое за информацию! У меня возник ещё один вопрос, могу ли я добавить к подобному выражению `Object.values(listTech[i].PROPERTY_152)[0]` проверку на "пустоту"? Некоторые объекты не содержат значений и из-за этого сыплются шибки.

Comment: @Виктор, смотря что подразумевается под пустотой... при отсутствии свойств в объекте (когда значением свойства `PROPERTY_152` является `{}`), вовсе не должно возникать ошибок: потому что вызов `Object.values(listTech[i].PROPERTY_152)` в этом случае вернет пустой массив `[]`, обращение к нулевому элементу которого просто вернет `undefined` (это и в таблице отобразится как текст "undefined", но ошибок не будет).

Comment: @ВикторУспенский, _«Я могу обратиться к этому объекту по его индексу?»_ - если объект в массиве, то да. Но у объектов индексом свойства является его имя, т.е. `listTech[i]['PROPERTY_152']` (а выражение `listTech[i][0]` это обращение к значению свойства с именем "0"). _«Могу ли я извлекать имя объекта?»_ - нет, у экземпляров объектов в JS не может быть имен (имена могут быть только у функций-конструкторов, "классов" объектов). А для получения имен свойств в объекте, можно использовать статический метод `Object.keys` - точно так же, как в примере использован статический метод `Object.values`.

Comment: у меня остался один маленький вопрос. Как мне в конструкцию Object.values(listTech[i].PROPERTY_152)[0] вместо "PROPERTY_152" подставить значение из переменной? Например, если есть переменная "nameObj" то как правильно написать Object.values(listTech[i].${nameObj})[0]? Как только не пробовал, всю голову сломал.

Comment: @ВикторУспенский, `listTech[i][nameObj][0]`, значение переменной `nameObj` будет преобразовано в строку автоматически. В случае отсутствия в объекте свойства с таким именем (которое в значении `nameObj`), вернется `undefined` - и тогда последующее чтение значения по индексу 0 вызовет ошибку.

Comment: с Object.keys разобрался сам немного раньше. Но спасибо за разъяснение.

Comment: скажите, могу я Вас как-то отблагодарить? Вы мне очень помогли.

Comment: @ВикторУспенский, думаю что нет, т.к. "плюсик" благодарности ответу уже поставлен)) Ну а в общем и целом, ответы на этом сайте бесплатны во всех смыслах, да и сам я ни в чем не нуждаюсь (кроме возврата лет затраченных на программинг, но их вернуть увы нельзя ).